# how can i make BCryptPasswordEncoder() work in spring because in my application can't find that classes

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

how can i make  BCryptPasswordEncoder() work in spring because in my application can't find that class about that and the message is not matching for dependencies i can't find another solve with mongodb  .

Comment: `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 5):

If you wan't to use `BCryptPasswordEncoder()` you must add to your dependencies (POM if your are using Maven) this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, you can use it in your Class with this import.
`import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;`

Answer (score 4):

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>     
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>     
    <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId> 
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Upvote.  Future readers.. be aware of this "undocumented" transient dependency : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java#L23L24  import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

Answer (score 2):

As Diego said you need you need [this.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/5.0.7.RELEASE)

Here is a quick snippet to show you how to use it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "admin@admin";
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        System.out.println("Encoded password is " + passwordEncoder.encode(password));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Don't put identical answers here.

Comment: Don't put identical answers here. You can upvote / downvote the existing answers or put comments on the respective answer.